# Google App Script : Error when attaching multiple images (Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp)

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, attachment

I am writing an automated script to send mails from my Google sheets and I want to attach multiple Images. With only one image everything works perfectly fine but when I want to attach two or more, it gives me this Error message:

Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp.

This is my code right now:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 1; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 3; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var image = DriveApp.getFileById(row[2]).getBlob();
    var image2 = DriveApp.getFileById(row[3]).getBlob();
    var subject = 'TAYDO 2021 Certificate';
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to:emailAddress, 
    subject:subject,   
    body:message,  
    attachments: [image.next(),image2]
  });
}
```

The App script has all permissions needed to run this script, and sheets, drive and everything is under the same Google Acc.
Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do `row[2]` and `row[3]` look like? If you log these values, what are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function attachimages() {
  let fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.imagesfolderid);
  let files = fldr.getFiles();
  let imgA = [];
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    if(file.getName().slice(0,3) == 'die') {
      imgA.push(file.getBlob().getAs('image/jpeg'))
    }
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail({to:'jimesteban@jimesteban.com',subject:'Test Images Attachment',body: 'See Attached Images', attachments:imgA});
}
```

My images happened to be named die1.jpg, die2.jpg .... and so on they are images of the faces of a dice.

This also worked for me:

```
function sendEmails() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const rg = sh.getRange(2, 1, 3, 4);
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let emailAddress = r[0];
    let message = r[1];
    let image1 = DriveApp.getFileById(r[2].toString()).getBlob();
    let image2 = DriveApp.getFileById(r[3].toString()).getBlob();
    let subject = 'Test Attach Images';
    MailApp.sendEmail({ to: emailAddress, subject: subject, body: message, attachments: [image1, image2] });
  });
}
```

Sheet0:

| Email | Message | Image1 | Image2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Redacted | Message1 | Redacted | Redacted |
| Redacted | Message2 | Redacted | Redacted |
| Redacted | Message3 | Redacted | Redacted |

Comment: Thanks! The problem is, that I have along list with over 100 different images, depending on the ID in the corresponding column, it should a attach a specific image to the mail that is send. So each row sends to a specific person with 1,2, or 3 images. And I don't know if your presented code can be used to do that...

Comment: r[2] and r[3] are ids

Comment: Oh the second code you posted works unfortunatley even less. It throws the same error message and says that lines 6 and 10 are faulty. I also don't know what the vs. command in line 6 is, I never saw this before

Comment: I  tested the second code and it works for me.  So you may have to make some small mods to get it to work for you, like changing sheet names etc.

Comment: Is your runtime V8.  If you still running Rhino then the second one won't work for you.  You should update to V8 runtime.